# Husky, turtlebot like simulators for ROS-lunar?

Tags: gazebo, ros-lunar, ros-indigo, gazebo-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been using ROS-Lunar, I tried Husky and Turtlebot but they both arent supported by Lunar.

Are there any similar simulators that I can get to use for my gazebo?

If not, is there any way by which I can use husky for lunar, or any other indigo supported package for lunar?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269662/husky,-turtlebot-like-simulators-for-ros-lunar?/) by [MukulKhanna](https://answers.ros.org/users/31696/mukulkhanna/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2017-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried downloading and compiling the [source](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_simulator)? You may also have to install the dependencies from the source too https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_simulator/issues/67.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MukulKhanna](https://answers.ros.org/users/31696/mukulkhanna/) on 2017-08-27**:
Yes, it becomes really messy because then I have to set all the environment variables, the launch files, the worlds etc and in the end I get stuck. I read somewhere that its not advisable to try to use packages meant for indigo into lunar or any other distro for that matter.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-27**:
That may be the only way for you to do this with that particular package.